# heroku login fails on installing CLI - windows

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface, heroku-toolbelt

downloaded Heroku toolbelt for windows, and run in the command line (from the installation dir) :

> heroku login

and get this error:

> heroku-cli: Installing CLI...end of file reached (EOFError) C:/Program
>   Files/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182:in `s
>   ysread_nonblock' C:/Program
>   Files/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182:in`r
>   ead_nonblock' C:/Program
>   Files/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.47.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:45:in `read
>   line' C:/Program
>   Files/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.47.0/lib/excon/response.rb:62:in`pa
>   rse' C:/Program
>   Files/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.47.0/lib/excon/middlewares/response_
>   parser.rb:6:in `response_call' C:/Program
>   Files/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.47.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:372:in`
>   response' C:/Program
>   Files/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.47.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:236:in
>   `request' C:/Program
>   Files/Heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.47.0/lib/excon.rb:230:in`get'
>   C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:235:in `manifest'
>   C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:248:in`url' C:/Program
>   Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:147:in `block (2 levels) in setup
>   ' C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:137:in`open'
>   C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:137:in `block in setup'
>   C:/Program Files/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:88:in`
>   mktmpdir' C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:135:in
>   `setup' C:/Program Files/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:27:in`start'
>   C:/Program Files/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in `'  !    Heroku client
>   internal error.  !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com  !
>   Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new
>
> ```
> Error:       end of file reached (EOFError) (Excon::Errors::SocketError)
> Command:     heroku login
> Version:     heroku/toolbelt/3.43.2 (i386-mingw32) ruby/2.1.7
>
>
> More information in C:/Users/busi/.heroku/error.log
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I was needed to set environment variable: HTTP_PROXY since I'm behind proxy